# Render multiple radio button groups in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

LWC renders first and last radio button groups fine but but none in between. If I reference 1 or 2 picklist group I am ok but 3 or more none of the picklist in in the middle render any values.

```
import { LightningElement,wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import LEASE_OBJECT from 
'@salesforce/schema/Lease_Payment_Term__c';
import Accounting_Type from 
'@salesforce/schema/Lease_Payment_Term__c.Accounting_Type__c';
import Type__c from '@salesforce/schema/Lease_Payment_Term__c.Type__c';
import Payment_Frequency from 
'@salesforce/schema/Lease_Payment_Term__c.Payment_Frequency__c';
export default class GetPickListValueInLWC extends LightningElement {

@track selectedValue;
@track options = [];
@track options1 = [];
@track options2 = [];

@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: LEASE_OBJECT })
objectInfo;

@wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName : 
Accounting_Type
}) ATPicklistValues ({error, data}) {
    if(data) {
        let optionsValues = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < data.values.length; i++) {
            optionsValues.push({
                label: data.values[i].label,
                value: data.values[i].value
            })
        }
        this.options = optionsValues;
        window.console.log('optionsValues ===> '+JSON.stringify(optionsValues));
    }
    else if(error) {
        window.console.log('error ===> '+JSON.stringify(error));
    }
   }


@wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId',  
    fieldApiName : Type__c
}) TPicklistValues ({error, data}) {
    if(data) {
        let optionsValues = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < data.values.length; i++) {
            optionsValues.push({
                label: data.values[i].label,
                value: data.values[i].value
            })
        }
        this.options1 = optionsValues;
        window.console.log('optionsValues ===> 
'+JSON.stringify(optionsValues));
    }
    else if(error) {
        window.console.log('error ===> '+JSON.stringify(error));
    }
}

 @wire(getPicklistValues, {
     recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName : Payment_Frequency
 }) TPicklistValues ({error, data}) {
     if(data) {
         let optionsValues = [];
         for(let i = 0; i < data.values.length; i++) {
             optionsValues.push({
                 label: data.values[i].label,
                 value: data.values[i].value
             })
         }
         this.options2 = optionsValues;
         window.console.log('optionsValues ===> '+JSON.stringify(optionsValues));
     }
     else if(error) {
         window.console.log('error ===> '+JSON.stringify(error));
     }
 }
```

html

```
<template>
<lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name="Lease_Payment_Term__c"
onsuccess={handleSuccess} onsubmit ={handleSubmit}>
<lightning-messages>
</lightning-messages>
<lightning-output-field field-name="Lease__c">
</lightning-output-field>
<lightning-input-field field-name="Name">
</lightning-input-field>
<lightning-radio-group name="ATradioGroup" if:true={wiredPicklistValues.data}
                      label="Accounting Type"
                      options={options}
                      value={value}
                      type="radio">
</lightning-radio-group>
<lightning-radio-group name="TradioGroup"
                      label="Type"
                      options={options1}
                      value={value}
                      type="radio">
</lightning-radio-group>
<lightning-radio-group name="PaymentradioGroup"
                      label="Payment Frequency"
                      options={options2}
                      value={selectedValue}
                      onchange={handleChange2}
                      type="radio">
</lightning-radio-group>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need this:

```
    let optionsValues = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < data.values.length; i++) {
        optionsValues.push({
            label: data.values[i].label,
            value: data.values[i].value
        })
    }
    this.options = optionsValues;
```

You can just put this:

```
    this.options = data.values;
```

The format retrieved by the "getPicklistValues" is ready to be used in the picklists, you don't need to create an array of your one.